# Congratulations on 19000 users!

Tags: discussion

A friend asked me about QCSE and I decided to visit just **randomly** at the time that we had 19,000 users!

[image]

Considering that we had [16 new users today](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) and 12 new users the day before, it would seem that we're getting about 28 new users per 48 hours, meaning that approximately every 30 minutes the number of users changes. That means that seeing a number like 19,000 doesn't happen often and doesn't last long when it does!

**I'd like to take a minute to reflect on how much we've grown since 2018 (5 year anniversary is coming up!) and thank everyone for continuing to contribute to this site in a way that has allowed it to grow so big!**

Thank you, and let's keep growing!